# List of all commits between 2 commits

Tags: git, jenkins, git-log

I am planning a new deployment process on our team.

For every build X, We have the **$last_commit_from_last_build** X-1
and the **$last_commit** on the existing build X.

We do not run builds in parallel, meaning that in build X there might be more then one commits, so we need to list those commits so we won't miss them.
For example, this might be the order of commits from the oldest to the newest:

(**last_commit_from_last_build**)(Build X-1), (**some_commit_1**, **some_commit_2**, **last_commit**)(Build X)

In Build X, we need to build all commits between $last_commit_from_last_build and $last_commit. 
**We want only the commits between $last_commit_from_last_build and $last_commit.**

So, we have decided to use: 
`git log $last_commit_from_last_build...$last_commit`.

The thing is it shows weird results, if we have the following history on GitHub:

[image: first image]

When we run `git log 3ec29f0...573e22e`

We receive the following results:

[image: second image]

The commits **bdd** and and **e57** are between these commits.

**637** is not!

What could go wrong in our logic, and is there a better way to get these requested list? This yields wrong build, and prevent us from going on with our project.

Answer (score 5):

First, head on over to [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).  Read the whole thing, or at least through the page titled "Experimenting With Git", and work through this until you understand the notion of *reachability* and how Git uses *references*.

Now you know all you need to know to understand the two and three dot syntaxes that the Git command line offers:

```
A...B
```

is the set of commits reachable from *either* name-or-hash-ID `A` *or* name-or-hash-ID `B`, but not from *both* names.  Meanwhile:

```
A..B
```

is the set of commits reachable from `B`, excluding the set of commits reachable from `A`.  **This is probably, but not necessarily, what you want.**

When commit `A` is an ancestor of commit `B`, you may want a different set than either of these.  You might, in particular, want the set of all commits starting from `A` that are *descendants of* `A` and *ancestors of* `B`.  There is no universal syntax for this, but it is available through `git rev-list` (and hence through `git log`) as:

```
git rev-list --ancestry-path A..B
```

Note that this omits `A` but includes `B`, just like the `A..B` variant without `--ancestry-path`.  (You can add `--boundary` to include `A` here, but beware of some odd side effects from `--boundary` in more general cases.)

The variant with `--ancestry-path` is what you want if a simple `A..B` is not what you want.  The two variations, between them, generally capture the somewhat slippery notion of "between" in a directed, acyclic graph.

Answer (score 0):

Like the OP, I had also noticed that the order chosen by GitHub to display the commits is not that "reliable", or at least not directly related to the underlying graph relation, as it seems that the chosen order depends on the timestamps of the commits (which can actually be changed when using commands such as [`git rebase -i …`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode)).

So the CLI-based approach explained in @torek's answer is definitely the way to go.

Otherwise, you can also use graphical commands such as [`gitk --all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk) to display the commit graph and have a better insight on the relation between commits, branches, and tags in a given repository.

For more details, see for example this tutorial [Use gitk to understand git](https://lostechies.com/joshuaflanagan/2010/09/03/use-gitk-to-understand-git/), which contains commented screenshots of `gitk`.